# PostgreSQL trigger function executing multiple times

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, triggers, insert

i am experimenting with triggers in postgreSQL, but the trigger insert i would like to make is being done twice for some reason(THIS IS USING THE FOR EACH ROW), when i changed it to **FOR EACH STATEMENT** it was executing the insert 3 times. this is my sql script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION forest_aud_func() returns trigger as $tree_stamp$ 
BEGIN
    insert into Audit values('k',124,'l');
    return null;
END;
$tree_stamp$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger forest_aud_ins after insert on forest
for each row execute procedure forest_aud_func()

insert into forest values('Blue',1600,'Austria','Health Ltd')
```

any idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: You should **not** return null from your trigger. That will stop processing the insert!

Comment: it still does the insert for me with return null, i don't think its the problem, or did you mean something else?

Comment: this is strange, because the manual clearly states that the insert (in your case the insert into `forest`) will be aborted if the trigger returns null.

Answer (score 2):

i found out the problem, i was always creating new triggers but not deleting the previous ones, so each time i do an insert it was firing all the triggers i had done, 
sorry and thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for giving the feedback.